# Select Item in a dropdown from website via Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

[image: I would like to select the options "Addition, Bulk, Reduction" using excel VBA]

I would like to select the options "Addition, Bulk, Reduction" using excel VBA

This what I have so far, but nothing is being selected.

```vb
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "my URL"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

'time_adjust_group_ident = Reduction

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = ie.document

doc.getElementById("time_adjust_group_ident").Value = "Reduction"

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for that, added already

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `time_adjust_group_ident_chosen`? That's the full ID...

Comment: Tried, "Object doesn't support this property or method". Apologies just new to this thoug.

Comment: @NathanielArnidoCongreso  if your problem was solved, please don't forget to mark it as answered. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Internet Explorer` object for this. Please take a look in the code below where I use `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` to make a HTTP request and get the HTML response as a string, and then parse it using the `HTMLFile` object.

I'm using the `CreateObject` method instead of adding the references via `Tools > References`, so you can run this code anywhere without having to add references manually every time you open this in a different machine.

In this example, I'm retrieving the children elements of the `language-selector` dropdown in a given website, and looping through it using a `For Each` to write each child element's content in a spreadsheet row.

```
Sub LoadHtml()
    
    Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select"
    
    Dim httpRequest As Object
    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    With httpRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .send
    End With
    
    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
    html.body.innerHTML = httpRequest.ResponseText
    
    Dim child As Object
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 1
    
    For Each child In html.getElementById("language-selector").Children
        Range("A" & row) = child.innerText
        row = row + 1
    Next
 
    
End Sub
```